# LiveCD Boot/Install

Tags: live-cd, sata

I have recently built a new computer and have been looking to dual-boot alongside Windows. Trying to boot/install off Ubuntu/Fedora/Arch live CDs has failed across all distros and I keep getting the error:

```
[34.5173939] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x1 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen
[34.517403] ata9: SError: {RecovData RecovComm UnrecovData Persist Proto HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt CommWake 10B8B Dispar BadCRC Handshk LinkSeq TrStaTrns UnrecFIR DevExch }
[34.517413] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[34.517420] ata9.00: cmd 60/08:00:00:6d:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[34.517420] res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x56 (ATA bus error)
[34.517433] ata9.00: status: { DRDY }
[34.667134] ata10.00 exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x1 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen
[34.667134] ata10: SError: {RecovData RecovComm UnrecovData Persist Proto HostInt 
PHYRdyChg PHYInt CommWake 10B8B Dispar BadCRC Handshk LinkSeq TrStaTrns UnrecFIR DevExch }
[34.667153] ata10.00: failed command: IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
[34.667159] ata10.00: cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 in
[34.667160] res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x56 (ATA bus error)
[34.667170] ata10.00: status: { DRDY }
```

I am using a new ASUS Z77 Sabertooth motherboard with a Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003 1TB 7200RPM hard drive.

I am not entirely sure why I can't even boot off the live CD? Any ideas?

---

All Distros were direct download from their respective websites, I have tried both CD boot with all distros and USB boot with Arch only.  I have just updated my BIOS as well an am still receiving the same error.

The fact that it happens on CD and USB tell's me it's not an optical drive issue.

All information I can find on this seems to relate to hard drives failing on already installed linux boxes or faulty SATA cables.  I am a bit confused why this issue would be preventing a CD/USB boot though.

Is there any more info I can provide that might help uncover the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the distro from a torrent or direct download? If you downloaded via torrent you, need to check the md5 checksum to make sure your torrent is not bad.

Also are you trying to install from USB or CD?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Sabertooth x79 and the problem I had was useing the Xdock and the intel and marvel HDD ports, so I used the regular HDD  ports and I was able to boot both live disks and install Ubuntu ....

So I believe it is a driver problem with the Asus Intel and Marvel HDD drivers as there might not be non for linux ...

as well you might need to install Ubuntu that way first then hope Ubuntu can install
the Drivers, which they have done a pretty good job of by the way, for instance my Wireless USB works great, and I had a hell of a time getting the driver working with windows , yet Ubuntu did all that automatically ...

Hope that helps ..

-Mark