# Ubuntu installation freeze

Tags: 14.04, freeze

I got this when trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 (x64) (tried with DVD and Flash drive):

```
[     3.280511] ACPI PCC probe failed.

[    34.929862] ata8.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen

[    34.929870] ata8: SError: { RecovData RecovComm UnrecovData Persist Proto HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt CommWake 10B8B Dispar BadCRC Handshk LinkSeq TrStaTrns UnrecFIS

[    34.929875] ata8.00: failed command: IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE

[    34.929880] ata8.00: cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00/00 tag 22 pio 512 in

[    34.929880]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x56 (ATA bus error)

[    34.929885] ata8.00: status: { DRDY }
```

I tried with F6 key (selected nomodeset alone and nomodeset with acpi=off) but it won't load... tried "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu" but nothing happens. My screen just freezes.

**My PC specifications:**

Motherboard: Asus P8Z77-V

CPU: Intel i5-3570

RAM: 8 GB DDR3

GPU: Gigabyte GTX 660 2 GB OC

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu ! Please edit your question to add details such as what are you trying to do , what is your ubuntu version and your pc hardware specifications. Also your image is not working.

Comment: Refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171885/livecd-boot-install).

Answer (score -1):

If you still have Windows on your PC, you can try Wubi. I don't recommend it because it doesn't support 13.04+, and it isn't very compatible with Windows 8. But if there is really no way to get the CD/flashdrive version to work, you can give it a shot.

Wubi is a program that basically installs Ubuntu within Windows, so you would get a dual boot PC. The downside to this is that you can't delete Windows, or you'll delete Ubuntu as well. That said, Windows treats Ubuntu like a program so you can uninstall Ubuntu from Windows like you would with any other software.

For more information visit https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide